# debugging react project on Brave on Mac giving Unable to launch browser: error

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, debugging, visual-studio-code, brave-browser

launch.json is as follows:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "runtimeExecutable": "/Applications/Brave Browser Dev.app/Contents/MacOS/Brave Browser Dev"
    }
  ]
}
```

and the error is:

> Unable to launch browser: "Unable to find Chrome version /Applications/Brave Browser Dev.app/Contents/MacOS/Brave Browser Dev. Available auto-discovered versions are: ["stable"]. You can set the "runtimeExecutable" in your launch.json to one of these, or provide an absolute path to the browser executable."

Comment: did you find solution for it

Comment: unfortunately no. i just use console.log for everything

Comment: Think you just needed to remove ` Dev` off the end of your `runtimeExecutable` value, unless you have a dev version of Brave installed (which you didn't, bc the launcher couldn't find the application at the path you specified)